# Swiper Slider Bug on Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, swiper.js

I used the Swiper Slider (http://idangero.us/swiper) on a clients Website. Btw I love this slider. But when using the 3d cube Effect it comes to 2  weird behaviours in Safari (Mac):

1) I cannot click the action link properly on the slider, because somehow the clickable area is narrower than the ac.

2) the navigation on the right disappears, only on the middle slides.

Here's the working example: (please view with safari) http://ep-communication.de

**Update** I fixed the navigation Problem with this Fix by trial and error:

```
.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-pagination {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 1px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 1px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 1px);
}
```

But the Click behaviour on Safari still exists: I set up a fiddle for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/m9q48aks/

On Safari: if you try to click on the link "Test" you see that that the active click area is moved.
On Chrome / Firefox: everything is fine

Comment: Then? You should ask the author of the library.

Comment: Have you found a solution? So far swiper 8 and safari16 issue remain